# Pyserial package doesnot read all the data from the COM port ( reads only 6000 to 6150 bytes always)

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I wrote a small pyserial interface to read the data from the COM port after issuing a command. For eg : in my case my system has a lot of network interface so i need to validate whether all the interfaces are up using **ifconfig** command. But when i gave this command , the output of the command is getting truncated at the last few lines. The approximate size of the output in bytes would be 6500-7000 bytes but i am receiving only around 6000-6150 bytes all the time. Please find my code below
'''

```
import serial
import time
com_serial = serial.Serial("COM6", 115200, timeout = 10)
com_serial.reset_input_buffer()
com_serial.write(b"ifconfig\n")
data_all = b" "
time.sleep(5)
while True:
   bytetoread = com_serial.inWaiting()
   time.sleep(2)
   print ("Bytetoread: " , bytetoread)
   data = com_serial.read(bytetoread)
   data_all += data
   if bytetoread < 1:
      break
print ("Data:", data_all)
com_serial.close()
```

'''
**Output:
Bytetoread: 3967
Bytetoread: 179
Bytetoread: 2049
Bytetoread: 0
**
Data: *********with missing data at the end.
I am not sure why the logs are missing?

I have tried another approach.
'''

```
import serial
import time
com_serial = serial.Serial("COM6", 115200, timeout = 10)
com_serial.reset_input_buffer()
com_serial.write(b"ifconfig\n")
time.sleep(5)
data_all = b" "   
data_all = com_serial.read(100000000)
print (data_all)
com_serial.close()
```

'''

Here also the last few logs are getting truncated.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause seems to be inadequate buffer size of the Tx and Rx serial buffer. By increasing the buffer size using .set_buffer_size() resolved the issue.

```
'''
import serial
import time
com_serial = serial.Serial("COM6", 115200, timeout = 10)
com_serial.set_buffer_size(rx_size = 12800, tx_size = 12800)
com_serial.reset_input_buffer()
com_serial.write(b"ifconfig\n")
data_all = b" "   
data_all = com_serial.read(100000000)
print (data_all)
com_serial.close()
```

'''